# Unsubscribe from listener in hook or in screen component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I created a hook to manipulate users data and one function is listener for users collection.
In hook I created subscriber function and inside that hook I unsubscribed from it using `useEffect`.
My question is is this good thing or maybe unsubscriber should be inside screen component?
Does my approach has cons?

```
export function useUser {
  let subscriber = () => {};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      subscriber();
    };
  }, []);

  const listenUsersCollection = () => {
    subscriber = firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(res => {...})
  }
}
```

In screen component I have:

```
...
const {listenUsersCollection} = useUser();

React.useEffect(() => {
  listenUsersCollection();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if I, by mistake, call the `listenUsersCollection` twice or more? Rare scenario, but your subscriber will be lost and not unsubscribed.

But generally speaking - there is no need to run this useEffect with `listenUsersCollection` outside of the hook. You should move it away from the screen component. Component will be cleaner and less chances to get an error. Also, easier to reuse the hook.

I prefer exporting the actual loaded `user` data from hooks like that, without anything else.

Example, using firebase 9 modular SDK:

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { onSnapshot, collection, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const col = collection(db, "users");

export function useUsersData(queryParams) {
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState(undefined);

  const _q = useMemo(() => {
    return query(col, ...(queryParams || []));
  }, [queryParams])

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(_q, (snapshot) => {
      // Or use another mapping function, classes, anything.
      const users = snapshot.docs.map(x => ({
        id: x.id,
        ...x.data()
      }))
      setUsersData(users);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [_q]);

  return usersData;
}
```

Usage:

```
// No params passed, load all the collection
const allUsers = useUsersData();

// If you want to pass a parameter that is not 
// a primitive or a string
// memoize it!!!
const usersFilter = useMemo(() => {
  return [
    where("firstName", "==", "test"),
    limit(3)
  ];
}, []);
const usersFiltered = useUsersData(usersFilter);
```

As you can see, all the loading and cleaning-up logic is inside the hook, and the component that uses this hook is as clear as possible.